# How do I assign a data-attribute to each <td> element in a kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Since kendo doesn't have cell-templating per se, I've decided to add a data attribute to each cell inside a kendo grid.

I need a "data-column" attribute to each  element inside a kendo grid, so that each of them can be uniquely identified with columns.field name.

Is there an out of the box way to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at Row Templates? http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/rowtemplate  You could set data-attributes on the TDs as part of the row template.

Comment: Just found a solution and you don't need row templates. Just set the attributes object in table.columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it's out-of-the-box. Use columns.attributes object to set DOM attributes to each TD.

Comment: Do you have an example?